# function.fopen: failed to open stream: Permission denied in PHP

Tags: php, linux, permissions, file-permissions

I'm trying to create XML sitemaps for my website from my PHP application. The idea is to either create a new file or overwrite an existing file. When I call fopen, I get the following error:

```
[function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

I'm trying to write to the webroot and its permissions are: 755. This means that the owner has write permission, right? What do I need to do to make my script be able to write to this folder? 777 would be a bad thing, right? Can I run my script as owner somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Need more info about the platform.

Comment: It's running LAMP. What information do you need?

Comment: Please tell me it's not trying to write files into the same tree it's executing code from.

Comment: @Ignacio: Linux 2.6.9-89.35.1.EL #1 Tue Jan 18 17:34:23 EST 2011 i686

Comment: @staticsan - no, it's not executing in the web root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, as you've said, using 777 could be huge mistake. The webserver doesn't run with the same user as you use to create files and folders.

You have some options:

- Run the sitemap creation as a cronjob, using an user with rights to write there, other than the apache user.
- Put the sitemap in another directory, and the set up a `302 Redirect` or a symlink. In this case, if you have a security issue that let's someone to write your `sitemap.xml`, at least they'll not be able to create another file with a more dangerous extensions (like PHP, which may result in a site intrusion).
- Make a rewrite rule to redirect any hit to sitemap.xml, to a php script that outputs the appropriate XML.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a beginner and I had this problem as well.  I am using Ubuntu linux w/ php and apache

- Write a php script w/ the following: `<?php exec('whoami'); ?>` and run it on your server.  This tells you who the current user of the script is
- SSH to your server.
- Make a group that has read and write access to the files you need.
- Make group have read, write,  and execute on folders you need.
- Make the current user you found in the first step, part of the group that has access to the files you need.
- Restart Apache: `sudo apachectl restart`

> main commands you need are:

- groupadd: Create a new group
- usermod: add your user to a new group
- chgrp: changes files / folders to group you specify
- chmod: changes permissions on the files / folders you specify.
  All the commands you need are here: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialManagingGroups.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have ACL enabled on the webroot partition just grant the web server username full rights

```
setfacl -m u:apache:rwx /var/www/html
```

Replace `apache` with the web server username and `/var/www/html` with your webroot location.

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem

Looks like apache is running as **nobody** in the nobody group

so if you do a

```
useradd -G nobody youruser

chown -R youruser:nobody .
```

Then change the permission to 0775

```
chmod -R 0775 .
```

or you may add nobody to your usergroup

```
useradd -G nobody yourgroup
```

this be a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Does it work with group write enabled (i.e. 775)?
Check your group permissions for the directory the file is in. As long as your PHP user (usually www-data) is part of that group, and it's the only user, you should be fine with 775 (or even 774).

Answer (score 0):

Like Pascal said!
just find your apache user

```
<?php exec'whoami'; ?>
```

and then

```
useradd -G username username2
chown -R username:username2 .
chmod -R 0775 .
```

And its done!
Thank you Pascal!

Answer (score -1):

777 is pretty normal, because PHP does not run as you, it runs as a PHP user, Apache, etc. The fact is, your webhost should have a higher set of permissions that prevents other users from writing/deleting your files.

Comment: 0777 is not normal. There should be no reason for others to have write permissions, ever.

Comment: That really depends on your host, the operating system, apache configuration, and setup. But, honestly I have found no problem with doing that, and have done extensive penetration testing. Really, as long as your host is doing what they should, it isn't a problem. But you are right about others, 775 should be more than enough.