# File rename failing on web server

Tags: php, permissions

I have the following script which works fine locally:

```
    <?php

//Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($handle = opendir('instance/system/application/images/dir/testimages/')){

    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))){
        $newName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);
        rename($fileName, $newName);
    }

    echo "All files have been renamed";
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

However when run on the web server I get the following error:

Warning: rename(.,.) [function.rename]: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\rename.php on line 10

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Cheers

Note:

I am using IIS7 and a windows server.

Comment: Which user owns instance/system/application/images/dir/testimages/, what are the access rights, under which user does the http servers runs ?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253670/php-function-fopen-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied

Comment: ensure that the folder dir also have permissions granted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

In windows, go to the directory where you want to rename files, right click, and look at the permissions for both the folder and the files within. Whatever the process is running the web server needs to have permissions to modify those files, or create new files in the directory.

Secondly, and more subtly - I think the root cause is a bug. In the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php), there's a comment suggesting that rename will put the file in the current working directory unless you specify your full directory path in the "to" argument.
So, if you are trying to rename "c:\instance/system/application/images/dir/testimages/banana pic.jpg" to banana_pic.jpg, your current code will write that to the current working directory - probably the location of php.exe - that will fail.

I'd try to specify the folder in which you want the renamed file to be placed, and see if that works...

Comment: So I need to do this: 

        rename($fileName, 'instance/system/application/images/dir/testimages/'.$newName);

Comment: rename('instance/system/application/images/dir/testimages/'.$fileName, 'instance/system/application/images/dir/testimages/'.$newName); might do it...

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This comment is not appropriate for a windows server. I didn't realise this when I commented. This is appropriate for linux, not windows.

You do not have permission to edit the image so need to chmod() the file:

The chmod() function changed the permissions of the file so you can rename it. The "777" means that anyone can (for a millisecond) change, read and execute the file. Then you write it back to "644", so that anyone can read, but only you can change the file. This second step is for security. You don't want files on your server editable and executable by everyone.

```
<?php

//Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if ($handle = opendir('instance/system/application/images/dir/testimages/')){

    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))){
        $newName = str_replace(" ", "_", $fileName);
        chmod($fileName, 777);
        rename($fileName, $newName);
        chmod($newName, 644);
    }

    echo "All files have been renamed";
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: assuming you have permitions to chmod the file.

Comment: This is indeed an assumption, though on the majority of standard webhosting packages this is the case.

Comment: Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: Permission denied in C:\inetpub\vhosts\domain.com\httpdocs\rename.php on line 12 I have got this error...I am using a windows box

Comment: I didn't see that it was a windows box. This comment would not be appropriate for that. I'll make that clear in my commment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Set permission to files You want to rename to 777.
In file manager, like, filezilla, right click on file and set permissions.
Or just google: set permissions to files on server.
You can try through PHP too: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 0):

In order to rename or chmod a file, you need to have access to do that. This means that the file should be either owned by the webserver process, or should be with appropriate mods that allow it to be changed by anyone (like 777)

Comment: Is this linux specific, or can it be applied to windows web server?

Comment: The chmod 777 is linux specific.
In windows there are different ways. Try this: 
cacls myfile.txt /p everyone:f